# Composer does not work with oh-my-zsh

Tags: macos, terminal, oh-my-zsh

I have installed composer on my Mac and it works just fine.

I have an issue with composer when i load oh-my-zsh and typing "composer" in terminal gives me following random `????%`  on the screen.

When i disable oh-my-zsh by renaming .zshrc in home, it agains begin to work.

Following is my `.bash_profile` file.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin:$PATH
```

And here is my .zshrc file

```
# Path to your oh-my-zsh configuration.
ZSH=$HOME/.oh-my-zsh

# Set name of the theme to load.
# Look in ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/
# Optionally, if you set this to "random", it'll load a random theme each
# time that oh-my-zsh is loaded.
ZSH_THEME="azhararmar"

# Example aliases
# alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
# alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"

# Set to this to use case-sensitive completion
# CASE_SENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment this to disable bi-weekly auto-update checks
# DISABLE_AUTO_UPDATE="true"

# Uncomment to change how often before auto-updates occur? (in days)
# export UPDATE_ZSH_DAYS=13

# Uncomment following line if you want to disable colors in ls
# DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true"

# Uncomment following line if you want to disable autosetting terminal title.
# DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"

# Uncomment following line if you want to disable command autocorrection
# DISABLE_CORRECTION="true"

# Uncomment following line if you want red dots to be displayed while waiting for completion
# COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"

# Uncomment following line if you want to disable marking untracked files under
# VCS as dirty. This makes repository status check for large repositories much,
# much faster.
# DISABLE_UNTRACKED_FILES_DIRTY="true"

# Uncomment following line if you want to  shown in the command execution time stamp 
# in the history command output. The optional three formats: "mm/dd/yyyy"|"dd.mm.yyyy"|
# yyyy-mm-dd
# HIST_STAMPS="mm/dd/yyyy"

# Which plugins would you like to load? (plugins can be found in ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/*)
# Custom plugins may be added to ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
plugins=(git)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

# User configuration

export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
# export MANPATH="/usr/local/man:$MANPATH"

# # Preferred editor for local and remote sessions
# if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]]; then
#   export EDITOR='vim'
# else
#   export EDITOR='mvim'
# fi

# Compilation flags
# export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"

# ssh
# export SSH_KEY_PATH="~/.ssh/dsa_id"
```

What could possibly be wrong ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You most likely had an alias setup in your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` file. You will need to move this over to the `.zshrc` file.

`alias "composer"="php ~/.composer/composer.phar"`

Answer (score 19):

Just run:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have already moved your `composer.phar` to `/usr/local/bin/composer` you can use:

```
alias composer="/usr/local/bin/composer"
```

Answer (score 3):

In the .zshrc file.

```
# Which plugins would you like to load? (plugins can be found in ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/*)
# Custom plugins may be added to ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
# Add wisely, as too many plugins slow down shell startup.
plugins=(git composer)
```

//EOF

https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/plugins/composer/composer.plugin.zsh

Answer (score 2):

Edit `~/.zshrc` and add:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

And refresh it:

```
. ~/.zshrc
```

By the way, there's a note about the `PATH` at the beginning of `~/.zshrc`:

```
# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.                                                                                                                    
# export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

First check composer is installed or not if composer is installed then you need

```
vim ~/.zshrc
```

add bellow line

```
alias composer="php /usr/local/bin/composer.phar"
```

How can check composer is installed or not if your normal terminal is working then **composer --version** if your normal terminal show same error. **cd /usr/local/bin/** check composer.phar is available or not.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open `.zshrc` and update `plugins=(...other composer)` ...other is your other plugins
2. Go to `.composer/lalit*/` and type these commands: *= name of user

`php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"`

`php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === 'e0012edf3e80b6978849f5eff0d4b4e4c79ff1609dd1e613307e16318854d24ae64f26d17af3ef0bf7cfb710ca74755a') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"`

`php composer-setup.php`